# Activity in fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation-drawer

So i created a navigationDrawer and i have a problem

I need to put my activity

> **ActivitySec**

```
package com.calculatorvamal.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SecondAct2 extends Activity implements TextWatcher {


    private EditText Result;
    private String Operation;
    private EditText editYear;
    private EditText editCapacity;
    private Button calc;
    private RadioButton radioD;
    private RadioButton radioB;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_home2);
        TextView Year = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Year);

        TextView Capacity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Capacity);
        editYear = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editYear);
        editYear.addTextChangedListener(this);
        editCapacity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCapacity);
        final EditText Result = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Result);
        final Button calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calc);
        final RadioButton radioD = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioD);
        final RadioButton radioB = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioB);

        TextWatcher listener = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                if (editYear.getText().toString().length() == 0 || editCapacity.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    calc.setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    calc.setEnabled(true);
                }

            }
        };

        editYear.addTextChangedListener(listener);
        editCapacity.addTextChangedListener(listener);

        calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        int edityear_value = Integer.parseInt(editYear.getText().toString());//Convert to intger
                                        double result = 0;
                                        int NumberCapacity = Integer.parseInt(editCapacity.getText().toString());//Convert to intger

                                        if (radioB.isChecked()) {


                                            switch (edityear_value) {

                                                case 2004:
                                                    Operation = "2004";
                                                    break;
                                                case 2005:
                                                    Operation = "2005";
                                                    break;
                                                case 2006:
                                                    Operation = "2006";
                                                    break;
                                                case 2007:
                                                    Operation = "2007";
                                                    break;
                                                case 2008:
                                                    Operation = "2007";
                                                    break;
                                                case 2009:
                                                    Operation = "2009";
                                                    break;
                                                case 2010:
                                                    Operation = "2009";
                                                    break;
                                                case 2011:
                                                    Operation = "2011";
                                                    break;
                                                case 2012:
                                                    Operation = "2011";
                                                    break;
                                                case 2013:
                                                    Operation = "2013";
                                                    break;
                                                case 2014:
                                                    Operation = "2013";
                                                    break;
                                                default:

                                                    Operation = "error";

                                            }

                                        } else if (radioD.isChecked()) {

                                            switch (edityear_value) {

                                                case 2004:
                                                    Operation = "20041";
                                                    break;
                                                case 2005:
                                                    Operation = "20051";
                                                    break;
                                                case 2006:
                                                    Operation = "20061";
                                                    break;
                                                case 2007:
                                                    Operation = "20071";
                                                    break;
                                                case 2008:
                                                    Operation = "20071";
                                                    break;
                                                case 2009:
                                                    Operation = "20091";
                                                    break;
                                                case 2010:
                                                    Operation = "20091";
                                                    break;
                                                case 2011:
                                                    Operation = "20111";
                                                    break;
                                                case 2012:
                                                    Operation = "20111";
                                                    break;
                                                case 2013:
                                                    Operation = "20131";
                                                    break;
                                                case 2014:
                                                    Operation = "20131";
                                                    break;
                                                default:

                                                    Operation = "error";

                                            }
                                        }


                                        //Benzin


                                        if (NumberCapacity > 0 && NumberCapacity <= 1000) {

                                            if (Operation.equals("2004")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 0.52;

                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2005")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 0.50;

                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2006")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 0.47;

                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2007")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 0.44;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2009")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 0.43;

                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2009")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 0.43;

                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2011")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 0.42;

                                            }

                                            if (Operation.equals("2013")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 0.40;

                                            }
                                        }

                                        if (NumberCapacity > 1001 && NumberCapacity <= 1500) {


                                            if (Operation.equals("2004")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 0.67;

                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2005")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 0.63;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2006")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 0.60;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2007")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 0.56;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2009")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 0.55;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2011")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 0.54;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2013")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 0.52;
                                            }

                                        }
                                        if (NumberCapacity >= 1501 && NumberCapacity <= 2000) {


                                            if (Operation.equals("2004")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 1.00;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2005")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 0.95;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2006")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 0.89;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2007")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 0.84;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2009")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 0.83;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2011")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 0.82;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2013")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 0.80;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if (NumberCapacity >= 2001 && NumberCapacity <= 3000) {


                                            if (Operation.equals("2004")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 1.59;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2005")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 1.52;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2006")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 1.44;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2007")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 1.36;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2009")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 1.35;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2011")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 1.34;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2013")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 1.32;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if (NumberCapacity >= 3000) {


                                            if (Operation.equals("2004")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 3.57;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2005")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 3.56;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2006")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 3.55;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2007")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 3.54;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2009")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 3.53;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2011")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 3.52;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("2013")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 3.50;
                                            }
                                        }

                                        //Diesel
                                        if (NumberCapacity <= 1500) {

                                            if (Operation.equals("20041")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 0.67;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("20051")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 0.63;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("20061")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 0.60;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("20071")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 0.56;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("20091")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 0.55;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("20111")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 0.54;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("20131")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 0.52;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if (NumberCapacity >= 1501 && NumberCapacity <= 2500) {


                                            if (Operation.equals("20041")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 1.59;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("20051")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 1.52;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("20061")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 1.44;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("20071")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 1.36;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("20091")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 1.35;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("20111")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 1.34;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("20131")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 1.32;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if (NumberCapacity >= 2501) {


                                            if (Operation.equals("20041")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 3.57;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("20051")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 3.56;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("20061")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 3.55;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("20071")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 3.54;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("20091")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 3.53;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("20111")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 3.52;
                                            }
                                            if (Operation.equals("20131")) {
                                                result = NumberCapacity * 3.50;

                                            }

                                        }
                                        Result.setText(String.valueOf(result));//Set the value after calculate it

                                        //Set the value after calculate it


                                    }
                                }
        );


    }


    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        try {
            int no = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
            if (no < 9) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Autovehicolul nu trebuie sa fie mai vechi de 10 ani", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){}

    }
}
```

in my fragment clas

> **Fragment.class**

```
package com.calculatorvamal.app;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment(){}


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


        return rootView;
    }


}
```

i tried doing it another way with intent and start activity but it gives me a lag(30,40 milliseconds delay when starting) when activity is started.
Fell free to give any suggestion,thank you.

Comment: Activities do not go in fragment classes, why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: This is the only way i could think of it , i need the layout that my fragments inflates to have a functionality , i tried intent start activity , and it lags when activity is open , maybe there is a better solution of doing this i don't know , the only thing i could think it's puting my activity into fragments

Comment: You should read up on how to communicate between Activities and Fragments: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html. The gist though is that to go `Activity -> Fragment`; invoke a method of the Fragment, to go `Fragment -> Activity`; make an interface that the Activity must implement and call methods defined there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have misunderstood or not read up on how to communicate between Fragments and Activities. You should read up on how to do so: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html.

Also you should not mix your Fragment logic and your Activity logic. Actions to be performed with aspects or Views (such as button click listeners and list view creation etc) from your discreet Fragments and their layouts should be contained in the Fragment class. If you need to pass results from one to the other for various reasons then you can communicate between the separate entities like so:

**Passing information from Activity to Fragment:**

To send information to a fragment you need only define a method in the Fragment to receive it and call that from your Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    private MyFragment myFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_holder);
        myFragment = new MyFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment).commit();
    }

    private void testFragmentCommunication(String message)
    {
        myFragment.recievedCommunication(message);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment
{
    ...

    public boolean recievedCommunication(String message)
    {
        Log.d("MyFragment", "Recieved communication from Activity: " + message);
    }
    ...
}
```

**Passing information from Fragment to Activity:**

However if you need to pass information back from your Fragment to your Activity you will need to define an Interface for them to use:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment
{
    MyActivityInterface activityInterface;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try
        {
            activityInterface = (MyActivityInterface) activity;
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Parent Activity deosn't implement 'MyActivityInterface'");
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement MyActivityInterface");
        }
    }

    public Interface MyAcyivityInterface
    {
        public void onMessageReceived();
    }

    private void testActivityCommunication()
    {
        activityInterface.onMessageReceived(String message);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyFragment.MyActivityInterface
{
    private MyFragment myFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_holder);
        myFragment = new MyFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    public void onMessageReceived(String message)
    {
        Log.d("MyActivity", "Recieved communication from Fragment: " + message);
    }
}
```

Comment: i will go trouch youre information and i think i will finaly succed, best of luck to you sir and thank you

Comment: You are welcome. Please note my edit (2nd paragraph) where I touch on keeping the logic for Activity and Fragment separate too.